# Use pg gem with ruby on os x

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks

I am trying to create a script that will connect to a remote postgresql server. I am using mavericks os x with postgresql and ruby installed on my local computer, but when I try to load pg into a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'
```

I get the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from submit.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

I have installed os x command line tools and ran the following commands:

```
sudo gem install pg
sudo PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/ gem install pg
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

It seems like it installs correctly but it still can't find the pg function. I installed postgresql with brew. My version of ruby is 2.0.0 and psql is 9.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your interpreter is running Ruby 2.0. It's possible that your `gem` installer is an pre-2.0 version and installing your gems to non-2.0 location. You can verify by running

`gem -v`

If this is the case check if your system has a `gem2.0` binary that you can use like so:

`sudo gem2.0 install pg`

Comment: Thanks for the response! My ruby version is ruby 2.1.1p76, and gem is v 2.2.2. Is it possible that my newer version is giving me the issues?

Comment: Try `gem environment`. It should tell you where your gems (and for what ruby versions) are beings installed - post it here.